What other channels besides /proc are there to obtain process information？
We know that process information can be obtained from the /proc directory, such as being able to see the PID of all processes, etc.
And many user commands, such as top, ps, and so on, essentially retrieve process information from /proc.
So, from the application layer, if there is no /proc, how can we obtain process information, such as the PID of all processes, just as we can see /proc/pid under /proc?

/proc is the interface that the kernel exposes to provide information about running processes. If it’s not available, there is no other API.
It is however possible to find out some process-related information without using /proc. In particular, sending a “0 signal” to a process can be used to determine whether it exists, if the sending process is permitted to signal it. If the calling process can ptrace the target process, it can run prctl to find out more information about the process.
The following example lists all accessible pids up to the pid assigned to the process itself (this is just an example; in practice you’d have to determine the size of pid_t and examine all possible values):
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pid_t pid, ourpid;

  // getpid() limits the search; just for the example
  for (pid = 1, ourpid = getpid(); pid < ourpid; pid++) {
    if (!kill(pid, 0)) {
      // The process exists
      printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)pid);
    }
  }
}

Running prctl inside the target process is left as an exercise; see Injecting into Processes for details.

However, sending signals to processes or attaching to target processes with ptrace requires the process's PID as a parameter. But aside from /proc, how can I obtain the process's PID? For instance, if I know the name of a process, how can I obtain its PID, and then use ptrace to attach to it or send it a signal?

If you know the name of a process, and want to determine its pid, you need to iterate over all processes until you find a match, same as with /proc. Obviously this is much less tractable in general than with /proc now that pids can cover a huge range, but on many systems it’s still workable.

What I want to know is, how can I get it? Without considering efficiency, is there any other channel besides /proc user layer? Taking the above example as an example, besides /proc, is there any other way to traverse all processes?

I’ve added some example code in the answer.

Not at all. You can consider these pseudo-filesystems the Linux API for these things. So, if you don't use that API, you don't have a way.
